# CentOS7 Apacheに複数SSLを設定したら再起動エラー

Tags: centos, apache, ssl

以前はdomain1のみで正常に動作しておりました。
いろんなサイトを見て、複数SSLを設置してみようと
下記のようにしてみたところ

> systemctl restart httpd

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

> systemctl status http

```
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since 水 2019-05-22 17:05:30 JST; 21s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 12625 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 7140 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 12623 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 12623 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 5月 22 17:05:30 ******.vs.sakura.ne.jp httpd[12623]: In order to read them you have to provide the pass phrases.
 5月 22 17:05:30 ******.vs.sakura.ne.jp httpd[12623]: Server ******.vs.sakura.ne.jp:443 (RSA)
 5月 22 17:05:30 ******.vs.sakura.ne.jp httpd[12623]: Enter pass phrase:Apache:mod_ssl:Error: Private key not found.
 5月 22 17:05:30 ******.vs.sakura.ne.jp httpd[12623]: **Stopped
 5月 22 17:05:30 ******.vs.sakura.ne.jp systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 5月 22 17:05:30 ******.vs.sakura.ne.jp kill[12625]: kill: cannot find process ""
 5月 22 17:05:30 ******.vs.sakura.ne.jp systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
 5月 22 17:05:30 ******.vs.sakura.ne.jp systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
 5月 22 17:05:30 ******.vs.sakura.ne.jp systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
 5月 22 17:05:30 ******.vs.sakura.ne.jp systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

このような状態です。
個人的には、「Enter pass phrase:Apache:mod_ssl:Error: Private key not found.」これが引っかかってるのですが。
修正のやり方がわからない状況です。

どなたか、教えていただけませんか。

> vhost.confの中身

```
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
#SSLMutex default
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
SSLCryptoDevice builtin

#domain1
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
  SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/server.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/internal.crt
  SSLCertificateFile      /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt

  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain1
  ServerName domain1:443
  AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

  <Directory "/var/www/html/domain1">
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
#  SSLEngine on
#  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
  SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/server_domain2.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/internal_domain2.crt
  SSLCertificateFile      /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/server_domain2.crt

#  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain2
#  ServerName domain2:443
#  AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

#  <Directory "/var/www/html/domain2">
#    AllowOverride All
#    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

１つ目のが最初に設定しており、正常に動作しておりました。
2つ目のが追加した分で、現在「#」でコメントにしているところを１行でもコメントを外すとエラーがでます。

> 5/23 追記
>   環境
>   ・CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
>   ・Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
>   ・Server built: Nov 5 2018 01:47:09
>   ・PHP 7.1.26

SSLPassPhraseDialogのところですが、対話に出来なかったので
現在は、「SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/etc/ssl/certs/pass_ssl.sh」のように変更してまして

```
#!/bin/sh
 case $1 in
   domain1:443);;
   domain2:443)
     echo 'パスワード';;
   esac
 exit 0
```

のようになっております。
domain1はパスワードを設定していないので、これでいいのかわかりませんが・・・・

> 5/24 解決
>   @Sieg、@take88
>   の情報を元に、色々と調べてserver_****.keyのパスフレーズを解除したら
>   すんなりと再起動でき、解決できました！！
>   ありがとうございます！

server_****.keyのパスフレーズ解除は

> openssl rsa -in  /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/server_****.key -out /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/server_****.key

Comment: Apacheのバージョンなど環境情報を記載してください。ところで`SSLPassPhraseDialog`の設定が`builtin`になっていますがパスフレーズの対話入力はできましたか？

Comment: @Sieg 
・CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
・Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
・Server built:   Nov  5 2018 01:47:09
・PHP 7.1.26

SSLPassPhraseDialogのところですが、対話に出来なかったので
現在は、「SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/etc/ssl/certs/pass_ssl.sh」のように変更してまして
#!/bin/sh
case $1 in
    domain1:443);;
    domain2:443)
        echo 'パスワード';;
esac
exit 0
のようになっております。domain1はパスワードを設定していないので、これでいいのかわかりませんが・・・・

この設定で「Enter pass phrase:Apache:mod_ssl:Error: Private key not found.」の部分は無くなりました。@Sieg

Comment: SSLPassPhraseDialog はそれでいいと思います。エラーの際、/var/log/httpd/error_log になにか出てませんか？

Comment: @take88 無事、解決できました。なぜかわかりませんがServer.keyのパスフレーズを解除したら、正常に動き再起動が無事に終わりました。みなさま、ありがとうございました！！m(_ _)m

Comment: @ココロパパ 解決したようでよかったです。おそらくVirtualHost毎にパスフレーズが違うため、複数の秘密鍵を対話入力できず秘密鍵を開けなかったものと思われます。VirtualHost中の秘密鍵のパスフレーズ指定は特殊なので、複数にする場合はドメインを判別してドメイン毎のパスフレーズを返却するシェルスクリプトにするといいです。（追加情報はコメントが埋もれてしまうため質問本文を編集して追記するといいです。あと、解決した場合は自己回答も出来ますので自己回答後、回答を承認して質問を解決させてください。）

Comment: @Sieg まだまだ使い方不慣れで、ご説明ありがとうございます！！
色々と調べてやってみます！m(_ _)m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5/24 解決
@Sieg、@take88
の情報を元に、色々と調べてserver_****.keyのパスフレーズを解除したら
すんなりと再起動でき、解決できました！！
ありがとうございます！

server_****.keyのパスフレーズ解除は

> openssl rsa -in /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/server_****.key -out /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/server_****.key